# upload fail the google api after redirecting to localhost

Tags: google-drive-api

After I run the following  code from:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

I get the link:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=792377765624-8l03cnfmj1km5gd27227kuaem37okdip.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A41245%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&state=8xHuMrgWMisZa7Hww6HpIZrRdkRTjq&access_type=offline
```

I click it and get new pages.

I was  not allowed to upload pictures here,sorry.

Because my score is low in stackoverflow

Finally, it tell me I can not connect to:

```
http://localhost:44637
```

Screenshots of the behaviour: https://blog.csdn.net/appleyuchi/article/details/102940981

Comment: Are you using the exact same code as in this Quickstart? Can you copy the error you are having?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.My difficulty is:I'm finally redirected to localhost:port/xxxx, and can not open. no  error all along the way.

Comment: So when you click at the link you provided, you are not redirected automatically to a page with the following message? `The authentication flow has completed, you may close this window.`. Are you trying to access 'localhost:port' manually? 'localhost:port' alone, without any query parameters, will not lead you anywhere, but you should get redirected just by clicking the link you provided.

Comment: Also, if you cannot upload pictures here, at least you can provide a link to those pictures?

Comment: Thanks for your replies,I'll upload the pictures to my own blog and then post here.

Comment: https://blog.csdn.net/appleyuchi/article/details/102940981   This link is under checked by the company who operate the blog site，it can be accessed after the noon of tommorrow.

Comment: And yes,I don't get `The authentication flow has completed, you may close this window.` the information I finanally got is:"Connection refused" which is shown by the page.

Comment: According to the link you provided you were logged into multiple Google accounts. Are you sure the account from which you downloaded the credentials is the same as the one with which you grant authorization? The redirect you would get if that was the case is the same one you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies I have solved it now.Yes,it's caused by exactly what you said,you're really genius~!!!

Comment: I have upvoted all your comments~!MuchThanks~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshots you provided and the url you are getting redirected to, the problem is that the Google account with which you downloaded the credentials file is not the same as the one with which you grant authorization to Drive. Both should be the same, because the credentials file contains information that identifies the account that downloaded them.

Check these for further information on the authentication process:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer